# Is there anyway to sign maven package at github action workflows?

Tags: maven, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, maven-gpg-plugin

i'm running a GitHub Action workflow and have failing error when try to run maven install.
it's required me to sign before i can install maven packages.
here my workflow yml file :

```
name: Github Action

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - release/*
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * 0'
jobs:
  build:
    name: Main
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.operating-system }}
    strategy:
        matrix:
          java-version: [1.8]
          operating-system: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Prepare
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set Up Java Development Kit
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: ${{ matrix.java-version }}
      - name: Maven build clean, build, test and install
        run: |
          mvn clean
          mvn install
          mvn package --file pom.xml
```

And this is what i get :

```
gpg: directory '/${HOME}/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/${HOME}/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.278 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-03T06:56:51Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-artifacts) on project core: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
```

Is there any way to sign our packages with github action workflows?

Comment: Do you currently sign it in a CI environment? How does that work? Presumably the CI environment needs the secret key to sign. I expect you would need to add it as a secret in the GitHub repository that your workflow runs in.

Comment: Yes i've done that action  using env : ${secrets.ENVNAME)

Comment: Maybe this action can help you: https://github.com/samuelmeuli/action-maven-publish

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, it's great to have an action with github features, i have done it using github env as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common answer you are going to get is to use [samuelmeuli/action-maven-publish](https://github.com/samuelmeuli/action-maven-publish). There are two issues with this plugin - it writes the secret key file to disk in the home directory, and it does not allow you to customize your Apache Maven command-line to the fullest extent possible.

Instead, you can use GitHub actions secrets and the gpg command-line to install the gpg secret key, using instructions from [How to Sign and Release to The Central Repository with GitHub Actions](https://gist.github.com/sualeh/ae78dc16123899d7942bc38baba5203c).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is use [Sign Maven Plugin](https://www.simplify4u.org/sign-maven-plugin/) which is designed to use in CI/CD systems.

All needed configuration can be done by environment variables.

`Sign Maven Plugin` doesn't use `gpg` so you don't need any step with `gpg` initialization.

You should define secrets

- **SIGN_KEY** - armored GPG/PGP key - this is required
- **SIGN_KEY_ID** - key id in hex format - optional, first key from **SIGN_KEY** will be used
- **SIGN_KEY_PASS** - passphrase to decrypt private signing key - optional if key is not encrypted

In GitHub Action workflow you pass secrets to build:

```yaml
 - name: Maven build clean, build, test and install
   run: mvn ...
   env:
      SIGN_KEY: ${{ secrets.SIGN_KEY }}
      SIGN_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets. SIGN_KEY_ID }}
      SIGN_KEY_PASS: ${{ secrets. SIGN_KEY_PASS }}
```